# PHP Fill array with query

Tags: php

I'm trying to fill one array with the data obtained by one sql select query execution but I can't do it, if someone please could help me.

I'm still very new to programming on php so sorry for that, probably this is really bad coding but I don't know how to fill the array with the foreach loop.

The data returned by the sql database server is:

```
1 La Defense - Chateau de Vincennes
2 Porte Dauphine - Nation
3 Pont de Levallois Becon - Gallieni
3bis Gambetta - Porte des Lilas
4 Porte de Clignancourt - Mairie de Montrouge
5 Bobigny Pablo Picasso - Place d’Italie
6 Charles de Gaulle Etoile - Nation
7 Louis Leblanc - Pre Saint Gervais
8 Balard - Pointe du Lac
9 Pont de Sèvres - Mairie de Montreuil
10 Boulogne Pont de Saint Cloud - Gare d’Austerlit...
11 Chatelet - Mairie des Lilas
12 Front Populaire - Mairie d’Issy
13 Gare Saint Lazare - Olympiades
```

My php function is:

```
function select($tipoTte) {
       $connection = connectDB();

       $sql = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT linea FROM lugar_transporte WHERE tipoTte = ?");
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "s", $tipoTte);

       $query = $sql->execute();

       if(!$query)
          die();

       $result = $sql->store_result();

       $realresult = $sql->bind_result($linea);

       $rawdata = array();

       $sql->fetch();

       for($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++) {
          $rawdata[$i] = utf8_encode($linea);
       }

       disconnectDB($connection);
       return $rawdata;
}
```

How can I fill the rawdata array with all the rows from the query? I mean I want to rawdata have the data like this:

```
rawdata["Linea 1 La Défense - Chateau de Vincennes", "Linea 2 Porte Dauphine - Nation ", ...]
```

EDIT: OK, with the new version of the code I got:

```
rawdata["Linea 1 La Défense - Chateau de Vincennes", "Linea 1 La Défense - Chateau de Vincennes", "Linea 1 La Défense - Chateau de Vincennes", ...]
```

How can I do to iterate throw the rows of the query result? I don't know if I'm explaining myself correctly...

Comment: Try ....  $rawdata['linea'][] = $valor;

Comment: `$rawdata[] = 'Linea ' .  $valor;`

Comment: `rawdata['linea'] = $valor;` this is a syntax error missing `$`, also you may wish to use `$rawdata['linea'][] = $valor;` as others note

Comment: Thanks for your comments, now I have the array filled but with the same value always, (like this):                                                                                                     rawdata["Linea 1 La Défense - Chateau de Vincennes", "Linea 1 La Défense - Chateau de Vincennes", "Linea 1 La Défense - Chateau de Vincennes", ...]                                                                          how can I change the value in every iteration?

Comment: Despite my answer, try:
    var_dump( $realresult); 
and also:
    var_dump( $result );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so finally I do it, I have to work with incompatibilities between php versions and methods but here is the final version, I got the array as I wanted, thank you so much for all of you who helped me, specially Pedro Branco, if I could hug you I'd do it man.

So here's the final version if someone needs it or have the same problem:

```
function select($tipoTte) {
            $connection = connectDB();

            var_dump($result);*/

            $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT linea FROM lugar_transporte WHERE tipoTte = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $tipoTte);

            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->get_result();

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())    {
                    $rows[] = $row;
                    }
            $rawdata = array();
            $i = 0;

                    foreach($rows as $row)    {
                        $rawdata[$i] = $rows[$i];
                        $i++;
                }
                    var_dump($rawdata);

            $result->close();

                disconnectDB($connection);
                return $rawdata;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this edit, fixed it and tested it. It´s working with php7 and mysql 5.6.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$linea = "0";
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT linea FROM lugar_transporte WHERE tipoTte = ?";
$stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "s", $linea);
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
var_dump($result);
while($row = $result->fetch_array())    {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$rawdata = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($rows as $row)    {
    $rawdata[$i] = utf8_encode($row[$i]);
    echo $rawdata["$i"];
    $i++;
}

/* free result set */
$result->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: This don't work because of "tipoTte = $tipoTte" in the SELECT query, if I put 'metro' instead of $tipoTte works, but only show the first row "1 La Defense - Chateau de Vicennes"

Comment: I've tried with mysqli_stmt_bind_param() function before and it didn't work, if I try var_dump($result) it show me bool(false) so it fails I don't know why man.                                                                                             EDIT: I've tried var_dump($rows[i$]); and it showed me what I want, it's close man, I'm gonna try with echo

Comment: I just fixed it and tested it, try again please. It works on my server. You can place it in your function and replace $linea by your method variable ($tipoTte).

Comment: It works, but if I use the mysqli_stmt_bind_param()  function I cant use the fetch_array() function, it doesn't work, I suppose I have to use mysqli_fetch_array() but I'm trying to know how...

Comment: This codes works - no errors here. What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't know why but if I use mysqli_stmt_bind_param() then fetch_array() didn't work propertly...I think I'd could be because of my php version, I don't know. Finally I get what I want I write the solution here a couple days ago, thank you for your help man!